# Split function doesn't get the result that I expect

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regexextract

A1 value is `485065/1, 2, 3` and I expect `485065` and `1, 2, 3` 
but it comes out `485065` and `1, 2, 2003`.

```
=split(a1,"/",false)
```

Please help me why it does.

Comment: as you know, it was =split(a1,"/",false) I tried but it came out the above result.

Comment: this is done coz of sheets' autocorrection of numbers into dates. regex treats it as text even after the split so no autocorrection kicks in

Answer (score 0):

- use **`REGEXEXTRACT`** instead:

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.)/(.)")
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Or do this:

```
=SPLIT(A1, "/,", 1, 1)
```